# calculate bad month from the given csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, dataframe, path

I tried finding the five  worst months from the data but I'm not sure about the process as I'm very confused . The answer should be something like (June 2001, July 2002 )but when I tried to solve it my answer wasn't as expected. Only the data of January was sorted. This the the way I tried solving my question and the csv data file is also provided on the screenshot.

My solution is given below:

```
PATH = "tourist_arrival.csv"  

df = pd.read_csv(PATH)
print(df.sort_values(by=['Jan.','Feb.','Mar.','Apr.','May.','Jun.','Jul.','Aug.','Sep.','Oct.','Nov.','Dec.'],ascending=False))
```

[image]

Year  ,Jan.,Feb.,Mar.,Apr.,May.,Jun.,Jul.,Aug.,Sep.,Oct.,Nov.,Dec.,Total
1992,  17451,27489,31505,30682,29089,22469,20942,27338,24839,42647,32341,27561,334353
1993   ,19238,23931,30818,20121,20585,19602,13588,21583,23939,42242,30378,27542,293567
1994,  21735,24872,31586,27292,26232,22907,19739,27610,27959,39393,28008,29198,326531
1995  ,22207,28240,34219,33994,27843,25650,23980,27686,30569,46845,35782,26380,363395
1996  ,27886,29676,39336,36331,29728,26749,22684,29080,32181,47314,37650,34998,393613
1997,25585,32861,43177,35229,33456,26367,26091,35549,31981,56272,40173,35116,421857
1998,28822,37956,41338,41087,35814,29181,27895,36174,39664,62487,47403,35863,463684
1999,29752,38134,46218,40774,42712,31049,27193,38449,44117,66543,48865,37698,491504
2000,25307,38959,44944,43635,28363,26933,24480,34670,43523,59195,52993,40644,463646
2001,30454,38680,46709,39083,28345,13030,18329,25322,31170,41245,30282,18588,361237
2002,17176,20668,28815,21253,19887,17218,16621,21093,23752,35272,28723,24990,275468
2003,21215,24349,27737,25851,22704,20351,22661,27568,28724,45459,38398,33115,338132
2004,30988,35631,44290,33514,26802,19793,24860,33162,25496,43373,36381,31007,385297
2005,25477,20338,29875,23414,25541,22608,23996,36910,36066,51498,41505,38170,375398
2006,28769,25728,36873,21983,22870,26210,25183,33150,33362,49670,44119,36009,383926
2007,33192,39934,54722,40942,35854,31316,35437,44683,45552,70644,52273,42156,526705
2008,36913,46675,58735,38475,30410,24349,25427,40011,41622,66421,52399,38840,500277
2009,29278,40617,49567,43337,30037,31749,30432,44174,42771,72522,54423,41049,509956
2010,33645,49264,63058,45509,32542,33263,38991,54672,54848,79130,67537,50408,602867
2011,42622,56339,67565,59751,46202,46115,42661,71398,63033,96996,83460,60073,736215
2012,52501,66459,89151,69796,50317,53630,49995,71964,66383,86379,83173,63344,803092
2013,47846,67264,88697,65152,52834,54599,54011,68478,66755,99426,75485,57069,797616

Answer (score 0):

`melt` your DataFrame and then `sort_values`:

```
output = df.melt("Year", df.drop(["Year", "Total"], axis=1).columns, var_name="Month").sort_values("value").reset_index(drop=True)

>>> output
     Year Month  value
0    2001  Jun.  13030
1    1993  Jul.  13588
2    2002  Jul.  16621
3    2002  Jan.  17176
4    2002  Jun.  17218
..    ...   ...    ...
259  2012  Oct.  86379
260  2013  Mar.  88697
261  2012  Mar.  89151
262  2011  Oct.  96996
263  2013  Oct.  99426

[264 rows x 3 columns]
```

For just the 5 worst months, you can do:

```
>>> output.iloc[:5]
   Year Month  value
0  2001  Jun.  13030
1  1993  Jul.  13588
2  2002  Jul.  16621
3  2002  Jan.  17176
4  2002  Jun.  17218
```