# Sort data in a csv file according to year, month and no of tourist arrival only using numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

I'm trying to sort the data in the format as year, month and no of tourist arrival beginning with the five worst months according to the arrival of tourists using numpy. Now, I've seen in this thread [Sort data frame with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71131094/18555797) someone did that with help of pandas. I'm trying to achieve the same thing only with numpy.

The output should be like this

```
Year    Month   value
2001    Jun.    13030
1993    Jul.    13588
2002    Jul.    16621
2002    Jan.    17176
2002    Jun.    17218
```

I tried using the sort , lexsort, argsort but I'm not getting the result like the above.

```
FILE_PATH = "tourist_arrival.csv"

reader = np.loadtxt(FILE_PATH, delimiter=',', dtype=str)

print(reader)
```

The output of the file is:

```
array([['Year', 'Jan.', 'Feb.', 'Mar.', 'Apr.', 'May.', 'Jun.', 'Jul.',
        'Aug.', 'Sep.', 'Oct.', 'Nov.', 'Dec.', 'Total'],
       ['1992', '17451', '27489', '31505', '30682', '29089', '22469',
        '20942', '27338', '24839', '42647', '32341', '27561', '334353'],
       ['1993', '19238', '23931', '30818', '20121', '20585', '19602',
        '13588', '21583', '23939', '42242', '30378', '27542', '293567'],
       ['1994', '21735', '24872', '31586', '27292', '26232', '22907',
        '19739', '27610', '27959', '39393', '28008', '29198', '326531'],
       ['1995', '22207', '28240', '34219', '33994', '27843', '25650',
        '23980', '27686', '30569', '46845', '35782', '26380', '363395'],
       ['1996', '27886', '29676', '39336', '36331', '29728', '26749',
        '22684', '29080', '32181', '47314', '37650', '34998', '393613'],
       ['1997', '25585', '32861', '43177', '35229', '33456', '26367',
        '26091', '35549', '31981', '56272', '40173', '35116', '421857'],
       ['1998', '28822', '37956', '41338', '41087', '35814', '29181',
        '27895', '36174', '39664', '62487', '47403', '35863', '463684'],
       ['1999', '29752', '38134', '46218', '40774', '42712', '31049',
        '27193', '38449', '44117', '66543', '48865', '37698', '491504'],
       ['2000', '25307', '38959', '44944', '43635', '28363', '26933',
        '24480', '34670', '43523', '59195', '52993', '40644', '463646'],
       ['2001', '30454', '38680', '46709', '39083', '28345', '13030',
        '18329', '25322', '31170', '41245', '30282', '18588', '361237'],
       ['2002', '17176', '20668', '28815', '21253', '19887', '17218',
        '16621', '21093', '23752', '35272', '28723', '24990', '275468'],
       ['2003', '21215', '24349', '27737', '25851', '22704', '20351',
        '22661', '27568', '28724', '45459', '38398', '33115', '338132'],
       ['2004', '30988', '35631', '44290', '33514', '26802', '19793',
        '24860', '33162', '25496', '43373', '36381', '31007', '385297'],
       ['2005', '25477', '20338', '29875', '23414', '25541', '22608',
        '23996', '36910', '36066', '51498', '41505', '38170', '375398'],
       ['2006', '28769', '25728', '36873', '21983', '22870', '26210',
        '25183', '33150', '33362', '49670', '44119', '36009', '383926'],
       ['2007', '33192', '39934', '54722', '40942', '35854', '31316',
        '35437', '44683', '45552', '70644', '52273', '42156', '526705'],
       ['2008', '36913', '46675', '58735', '38475', '30410', '24349',
        '25427', '40011', '41622', '66421', '52399', '38840', '500277'],
       ['2009', '29278', '40617', '49567', '43337', '30037', '31749',
        '30432', '44174', '42771', '72522', '54423', '41049', '509956'],
       ['2010', '33645', '49264', '63058', '45509', '32542', '33263',
        '38991', '54672', '54848', '79130', '67537', '50408', '602867'],
       ['2011', '42622', '56339', '67565', '59751', '46202', '46115',
        '42661', '71398', '63033', '96996', '83460', '60073', '736215'],
       ['2012', '52501', '66459', '89151', '69796', '50317', '53630',
        '49995', '71964', '66383', '86379', '83173', '63344', '803092'],
       ['2013', '47846', '67264', '88697', '65152', '52834', '54599',
        '54011', '68478', '66755', '99426', '75485', '57069', '797616']],
      dtype='<U6')
```

Comment: If you only want to use numpy, you needn't include pandas tag.

Comment: you want to use a `rec_array`

Comment: you should show how you tried to use `sort`, `lexsort`, `argsort` and what results you got.